# Не показывает значение по умолчанию DropDownList ASP.NETCore

Tags: asp.net, dropdown

```
//список значений статуса для выпадающего списка
        Type enumType = typeof(ExecutionStatusOverrideEnum);
        Array enumValArray = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
        List<ExecutionStatusOverrideEnum> enumAccessList = new List<ExecutionStatusOverrideEnum>(enumValArray.Length);
        foreach (int val in enumValArray)
        {
            enumAccessList.Add((ExecutionStatusOverrideEnum)Enum.Parse(enumType, val.ToString()));
        }
        enumType = typeof(ExecutionStatusOverrideEnum);
        List<SelectListItem> executionStatusOverride = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var item in enumAccessList)
        {
            if (item == ExecutionStatusOverrideEnum.NotExecuted)
            {
                executionStatusOverride.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.ToString(), Selected = true, Value = item.ToString() }); //по умолчанию - not executed
            }
            else
            {
                executionStatusOverride.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.ToString(), Value = item.ToString() });
            }
        }
        ViewBag.ExecutionStatusOverride = executionStatusOverride;
```

Инициализиарую список, ставлю, чтобы значения NotExecuted было по умолчанию

Вот так вызываю в представлении:

```
<select asp-for="ExecutionStatusOverride" asp-items=@ViewBag.ExecutionStatusOverride class="form-control input-sm"></select>
```

В общем показывает что угодно, но значение по умолчанию правильно не генерируется

Comment: А через Html хелперы не пробовали?

Comment: нет, не пробовал. Думаете есть смысл?

Comment: Смысл определенно есть, я всегда использовал хелперы и проблем особых не возникало, могу вам показать, если не знаете

Comment: И такой вопрос, у вас все элементы списка отображаются?

Comment: да, отображается все хорошо, проблема лишь в том, что не помечает значение по умолчанию(selected)

Comment: Кстати в ASP.NET Core asp-for, asp-items и есть хелперы. Я так понимаю вы говорите про те, что были до Core версии

Comment: Да, но мне почему-то казалось, что они и в Core версию вошли, видимо ошибся

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ExecutionStatusOverride, ViewBag.ExecutionStatusOverride as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)  - вставил вот такой хелпер, результат никак не отличается от того, что был изначально. Стоит заметить что одно значение он помечает как selected и оно при каждом обновлении всегда разное почему-то.

Comment: Именно, а так @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ExecutionStatusOverride, new SelectList(ViewBag.ExecutionStatusOverride as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, ViewBag.ExecutionStatusOverride[0])), вы зададите первый элемент коллекции как элемент по умолчанию

Comment: так выводит тип ListItem а не Text из него

Comment: А, это, уже задача приведения типов и проектирования модели отображения

Comment: В таком случае получается что моя инициализация SelectListItem в контроллере ни к чему, проще передать просто массив значений и указать в самом представлении какое из значений по счету дефолтное.   Для моей задачи это возможно и подойдет, но что если дефолтное значение высчитаывается по логике в контроллере и всегда может быть другим? В этом случае придеться передовать дополнительное значение в представление. Хм. это выглядит некрасиво.

Comment: В вашем случае да, ни к чему. Вы можете также высчитать новые значения, создать новую коллекцию или сделать это прямо в текущей, и передать её как модель или поместить во ViewBag.

Comment: А, понял что имеете ввиду, можете попробовать без инициализации SelectList, только и ваш список, что инициализируется в контроллере, должен быть того-же типа, например: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ExecutionStatusOverride, ViewBag.ExecutionStatusOverride as IEnumerable<SelectList>)`. А в контроллере вместо `List<SelectListItem> executionStatusOverride` использовать `SelectList executionStatusOverride`

Comment: Да, спасибо. Использовав SelectList заработало. Чисто для себя осталось неясным наличия свойства bool Selected в классе SelectListItem

Comment: Все же не работает как надо. Ситуация следующая - если использую в представлении <select asp-items=@ViewBag.ExecutionStatusOverride class="form-control input-sm"></select>  ----> все отлично работает. Если добавляю привязку asp-for :<select asp-for="ExecutionStatusOverride" asp-items=@ViewBag.ExecutionStatusOverride class="form-control input-sm"></select> ----->значение по умолчанию не срабатывает. Абсолютно такая же ситуация и с хелперами из MVC.